# Vue: Why does computed property require .value in v-model directive when declared in a store but not when declared in the component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar-framework

When I move a computed prop from my component to the store, I have to use .value in the v-model directive.

The two quasar select lists below are both working. They both display the state from the store, with the first one accessing the state from a computed property in the store and the second one accessing the state from a computed property in the component.

Both computed props are essentially the same implementation, why do I have to use **.value** in the first one's v-model directive?

```
    <q-select
        outlined
        v-model="store.warehouse.currentDepotCode.value" 
        :options="store.warehouse.getDepotSelectList()"
        emit-value
        map-options
        label="Select a Depot"
        class="q-ma-md"
    />
    
    <q-select
        outlined
        v-model="currentDepotCode" 
        :options="store.warehouse.getDepotSelectList()"
        emit-value
        map-options
        label="Select a Depot"
        class="q-ma-md"
    />

  setup() {
    const store = inject("store");

    const currentDepotCode = computed({
        get(){
            return store.warehouse.state.currentDepot;
        },
        set(depotCode){
            store.warehouse.setCurrentDepot(depotCode);
        }
    });
    
    return {
        store,
        currentDepotCode,  
    };
```

store/index.js

```
    const state = reactive({
        depots,
        currentDepot: 'VIC',
    });

    const currentDepotCode = computed({
        get(){
            return state.currentDepot;
        },
        set(depotCode){
            state.currentDepot = depotCode;
        }
    });

    export default {
        state: readonly(state),
        ...methods,
        ...getters,
        currentDepotCode,
    };
```

(I am using a computed prop because the select component will appear on a number of pages so I want to use a setter function and I dont want to repeat the computed prop on every page, so its going in the store. Happy to have comments on this set up too).

Answer (score 1):

i think because `q-select` options is an array of objects,
`store.warehouse.getDepotSelectList()`
the real value of each element

ex:
`[{ key: 1, value: 'first' }, { key: 2, value: 'second' }]`

because in documentation it's using value directly
https://quasar.dev/vue-components/select

Comment: But shouldnt that be the same for both implementations? To my mind its something that Vue is doing "under the hood" in the component implementation, that it is not doing when implemented in a js object (even though it is reactive)